# Upload content to ArcGIS Portal from Python

Tags: arcgis-portal

Is there a way to upload new, custom data to an ArcGIS Portal instance from Python?

In essence, I want to programmatically execute the steps involved in adding new GeoJSON content via the web-interface, but do everything from within a python script.

The context is that I'm doing analysis in Python on one machine, generating results, and want to upload that data as a feature layer to the GIS system.

I cannot use `arcpy`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Make use of the [ArcGIS Python API](https://developers.arcgis.com/python/). It works with both ArcGIS Online and ArcGIS Portal. It does *not* require ArcGIS Pro/ArcMap to be installed. Just Python 3.x

See this example, [Automate loading data into the ArcGIS Online cloud using ArcGIS API for Python](https://developers.arcgis.com/labs/python/import-data/), which seems to do exactly what you want.